# xp pro desktop pc hp v40 printer dsl wired combo modem new asus windows 7 laptop

Tags: wireless-networking

I have an xp pro desktop that is connected to a wireless dsl network.My wife ahs a windows 7 laptop that we cant get to see the printer connected to the desktop. please help

Comment: The title to this post, tells absolutely nothing other the problem.  Furthermore, I would be more than happy to assist, but many many more details are needed.  Have you shared the printer over the network? If so, can you connect to it from new laptop? Have you setup other machines on the network to print to it?

Comment: i appreciate your help. the title is merely a list of the hardware/ software involved. I have followed all the networking isntructions i could find to get the printer recognized on the network  The windows 7 laptop will see the xp pc but not the printer. I have turned off home group in w7 and defined the rinter as shared. searched and found hp network driver. I can print from pc or laptop  through usb hookup.Thanks in advance for your help. I am puzzled

Comment: the lap top sees the network and the desktop but does not see the resources of the desktop pc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned off Windows Firewall on the Win 7 machine? Previously, while working on a client deployment back at Launch of Win 7, we had issues with initial setup of network printers, because we had turned Windows Firewall off.  The solution was to turn the Windows Firewall Service On, temporarily while we setup the printers, and then once we could print, we turned the service back off.

Also, maybe reading through this guide from MS would help too. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/help/sharing-files-and-printers-with-different-versions-of-windows